# Видео из ютуба ломает дизайн

Tags: вёрстка, youtube, видео, кроссбраузерность

Видео из ютуба встроено стандартным ютуюбовским способом через iframe:

```
<iframe  width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/W5aLrW4MP2I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при прокручивании страницы, блок с видео оказывается поверх блока меню в шапке сайта, z-индекс которого выставлен выше z-индекса iframe.

Вот сама [страница](http://club75.ru/new.php) с проблемой. (сайт одностраничник)
Видео находится с разделе "Новости"

Проблема возникает только в яндекс-браузере. Гугл-хром и даже эксплорер выводят безупречно.

Яндекс-браузер выдаёт ошибку, хотя само видео проигрывается нормально.
Описание ошибки:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" 
from accessing a frame with origin "http://club75.ru". 
Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Гугль-хром ошибки не выдаёт, хотя вроде бы движок у яндекса такой же.

**И собственно вопрос:** в какую сторону танцевать (с бубном)?
Может нужно делать какой-то свой модуль для встраивания видео (может порекомендуете готовый) или это лечится как-то иначе?

Comment: Ну, очевидно, оно хочет, чтобы протокол, домен и порты совпадали.

Comment: Попробуй выставить z-index равным iframe

Answer (score 2):

> Проблема возникает только в яндекс-браузере.

Не только. Проверьте ещё в Maxthon и Safari (win).

---

В конец адреса на видео в теге iframe попробуй добавить `?wmode=transparent`, например:

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/W5aLrW4MP2I?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Сенкс, ксендз! Всё заработало.